# Is it possible to cycle to the South Pole?

Tags: winter

I know this is not proper form, but I figure it would be too interesting to folks here to pass up.  Helen Skelton is planning an [attempt to cycle to the South Pole](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/magazine-16345232) on a slightly odd looking all-terrain bike.

It rides on what are basically golf cart tires, has a suspension fork, 21-speed derailleur gearing, and rear disk brakes.

I'm personally a hair skeptical of the tubeless tires and the rear derailer that seems to clear the "ground" by only a few inches.  But the folks doing this have a lot of experience.

Is what they're planning even possible? What will be their biggest problems?

Comment: In the video they imply that they're going to be doing a lot of snowkiting (and maybe walking) and less with the bike.

Comment: I was woken up early this AM by a telemarketer, and then went on the net and saw this. I assumed this was just an excuse to post a cool link and voted to close, but later looked at this again and realized that it's a good question but that *the question is all in the title*. I added the last paragraph in an attempt to make that plain and keep others from making the same error I did, but please do roll my edits back if I've again missed the point?

Comment: "What will be their biggest problems?" - Crevasses for starters.

Comment: This still seems more likely to generate **[ideas or opinions, rather than answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)**. It does not seem at all like a [practical, answerable question based on actual problems that you face](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: I think the BBC article does a good job of explaining how you cycle to the South Pole.

Comment: As a side note, I weighed my old-school MTB and it weighs in at 38lbs.  It's beastly to ride at anything other than a moderate pace even with the thinner tires I swapped on (was originally 2.25", is now 1.875").  I can't imagine 40lbs and those monster wide tires!

Comment: Riding a bike to the South Pole absolutely can not be done without a significant support team. Getting **just myself** with gear, over crevasses in the Cascades is challenging. And I haven't had a bike to carry along.

Comment: [Update](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helen_Skelton#South_Pole): In 2012, Skelton raised more money for Sport Relief by becoming the first person to reach the South Pole using a bicycle. The bike was custom built for her trip, with 8-inch tyres. She also used skis and a kite to help her pull a sled containing 82 kg of supplies.[17] She covered 329 miles by kite ski, 103 by bike, and 68 by cross-country ski. She is also the first person to claim a world record for the fastest 100 km by kite ski, in seven hours 28 minutes, which was set during the trip (subject to verification).